# Does declaring type of something make the word specific?

Tags: grammar, articles

Having Checked [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/84954/difference-between-most-of-the-people-and-most-people) out, I want to know something beyond.

I have the following sentence:

> Nowadays, most of the IT companies adopt agile methodologies for their
>   software development process
>
> Nowadays, most IT companies adopt agile methodologies
>   for their software development process

However, I'm not exactly sure which one is correct. Since I think that the term `IT` has made the term `companies` **specific** and known. Is this deduction correct? Can we use the first form on this assumption?

Thank you.

Comment: It's "specific" as to the type of companies you're talking about (IT companies and not other kinds of companies), but your version without *the* refers to "most IT companies" in general.

Comment: Without prior reference such as @Clare might be hinting at, it's still acceptable. Compare 'Most of the banks ... / Most banks ...'.  It means precisely the same as your second variant, but the latter is preferable as it sounds less chatty, more formal and professional in register.

Comment: The argument is the same whether you use simple or compound nouns. Use *the* when you've identified the composition of the group (here, a group of *IT companies*), and leave it out when referring to the group in the generic sense.

Comment: Following on from @Lawrence, who beat me to it, 'Most of the sugar landed on the floor'. vs 'Most sugar comes from cane'.  You need the 'of' version to support demonstratives. 'Most of these IT companies ... '. Also - '(while/although) most X companies haven't, most *of the* Y companies have'. The latter isn't necessary, but seems to be the norm.

Comment: Thank you, you mean that both are correct? @Clare

Comment: Yes, I know. In fact, the second sentence comes more natural to me. However, for the reason I pointed out, I hesitate in using them. @EdwinAshworth

Comment: Thank you for your comprehensive response. So, do you mean although both are correct, the latter seems to be more natural? @PhilSweet

Comment: Neither is ungrammatical. You can still say 'Most dogs like sausages' even though you've identified/specified a single species. 'Most of the dogs like sausages' virtually demands that you're talking about an identified subset (say those in your boarding kennel). 'Most of the cats hunt by day' is ambiguous: it could be referencing an identified subset (the cats on the street say) or be talking about different cat species. And 'Most of the IT companies use clever strategies ...' is likewise ambiguous; it may be referring to an already-identified subset, or to all IT companies.

Comment: Yes both sentences are grammatical. But which one you would use depends on context.

Comment: No, the term "IT" has not made the term "companies" specific or known - whatever "known" means here.

Don't you think you'd find more useful help at SE English Language Learning?

Answer (score -2):

The second sentence is correct. 
A sentence beginning "Most of the IT companies..." must continue with "...that (do something)" or "...in (a place)" or some similar specifier to define a specific group of IT companies that are different from other IT companies.
This sentence is not talking about most of a specific group of IT companies, it's talking about most IT companies in general. Therefore, no "the."

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I'm still not convinced. If we look this statement from a higher level, It'll be somewhat challenging. Look, I'm talking about those companies which are engaged in IT industry (and not other industries).

Comment: In that case you'll say "THE companies in the IT industry." (definite article)

Comment: But your noun isn't "companies" it's "IT companies." If you don't further specify some set of IT companies, there should be no definite article.